# Symfony 3 change target of asset_url in config.yml

Tags: php, assetic, symfony

I am trying to better organize my generated assetics.  I configured then to be written into a web/dist of my project.  I want my asset_url to now read from that directory.

So far I have configured

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
        assets_base_urls:
            http:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/dist/'
```

I am getting the following error

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 314:
Unrecognized option "assets_base_urls" under "framework.templating"
```

anyone know what i could be doing wrong. i recently upgraded to 3.0

Comment: You should accept @xabbuh's answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony 2.7 introduced a new Asset component. The configuration must now be done under `framework.assets` (the old way is deprecated but still works until Symfony 2.8):

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_path: /dist
```